# speed and slow the ball using the button

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

Can you show me how to speed up and slow down the speed of the ball using the button when clicked,
I used the code but it hasn't worked yet,

```
    this.upButton = this.add.sprite(230, 530, 'down-bubble').setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    this.downButton = this.add.sprite(80, 530, 'up-bubble').setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    this.input.on('gameobjectup', function (pointer, gameobject) {

        if (gameobject === this.downButton &&  this.spinSpeed.timeScale > 100)
        {
            this.spinSpeed.timeScale -= 10.1;
        }
        else if (gameobject === this.upButton &&  this.spinSpeed.timeScale < 19.9)
        {
            this.spinSpeed.timeScale += 10.1;
        }

    });



generateDance() {

    this.spinSpeed = 0.003;

    return this.tweens.addCounter({
        from: 220,
        to: 160,
        duration: 9000,
        delay: 2000,
        ease: 'Sine.easeInOut',
        repeat: -1,
        yoyo: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to create the ball? And the code that calls your `generateDance()` method?

Comment: hello, sir,
This is the code that calls the ball

Answer (score 0):

generateBalls() {

```
    const hitArea = new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32);
    const hitAreaCallback = Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.Contains;        

    const circle = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(400, 300, 220);
    const balls  = this.add.group(null, { 
        key: 'balls', 
        frame: [0, 1, 5], 
        repeat: 5, 
        setScale: { x: 3, y: 3 },
        hitArea: hitArea,
        hitAreaCallback: hitAreaCallback,
    });

    // console.log(balls.getChildren().length);


    this.input.on('gameobjectover', function (pointer, gameObject) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

    this.input.on('gameobjectout', function (pointer, gameObject) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    this.upButton = this.add.sprite(230, 530, 'down-bubble').setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    this.downButton = this.add.sprite(80, 530, 'up-bubble').setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    this.input.on('gameobjectup', function (pointer, gameobject) {

        if (gameobject === this.downButton &&  this.spinSpeed.timeScale > 100)
        {
            this.spinSpeed.timeScale -= 10.1;
        }
        else if (gameobject === this.upButton &&  this.spinSpeed.timeScale < 19.9)
        {
            this.spinSpeed.timeScale += 10.1;
        }

    });
    Phaser.Actions.PlaceOnCircle( balls.getChildren(), circle);

    return balls;
}

generateDance() {

    this.spinSpeed = 0.003;
    // https://phaser.discourse.group/t/how-to-create-key-combo-with-custom-buttons/2622
    return this.tweens.addCounter({
        from: 220,
        to: 160,
        duration: 9000,
        delay: 2000,
        ease: 'Sine.easeInOut',
        repeat: -1,
        yoyo: true
    });
}
```

update() {
        Phaser.Actions.RotateAroundDistance( this.balls.getChildren(), { x: 400, y: 300 }, this.spinSpeed, this.dance.getValue());
        this.playerEyes.update();
        // this.buttonsspeed.update();

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preload(): void {

    this.load.image('sky', './src/games/gewgly/assets/images/sky.png');

    this.load.image('up-bubble', './src/games/gewgly/assets/images/up-bubble.png');
    this.load.image('down-bubble', './src/games/gewgly/assets/images/down-bubble.png');

    this.load.spritesheet('balls', './src/games/gewgly/assets/images/balls.png', { frameWidth: 17, frameHeight: 17 });

}


create(): void {

    this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    this.balls = this.generateBalls();    
    this.dance = this.generateDance();
    // this.buttonsspeed();

    this.playerEyes = new Eye(this.generateEyeArg(200,135,3.0));
}
```